# UITableViewCells content animation going haywire when tableview is scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I am playing around with animations. I have set up a `tableView` with a custom `tableViewCell` with a `UIView` in it. The `UIView` width is changing from 400 to 0 in 10 seconds. Now with the key nature of `tableView` the cells are rendered when the table is scrolled. This does certain things:

1. Cells that are animating when gone out of visible frame; the `UIView` gets disappeared.
2. When scrolled, some `UIView` starts animating when the cells become visible.

Here is the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellid, for: indexPath) as! listTableViewCell
    cell.testlabel.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let myCell = cell as? listTableViewCell {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, animations: {
            myCell.timeRemainingView.frame.size.width = 0
            self.loadViewIfNeeded()
        })
    }

}
```

Question: I want all the cells to start animating when the app starts and keep animating while I am scrolling.

[image]

UPDATE:

Here is what I have done. I am using CADisplayLink and running the animation that way. I am doing all this in the custom tableviewcell file. The only thing I need to figure out is custom duration for each cell. Here is the code:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    contentView.addSubview(timeRemainingView)
    contentView.addSubview(testlabel)
    contentView.bringSubviewToFront(testlabel)
    contentView.backgroundColor = .white

    let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(handleProgressAnimation))
    displayLink.add(to: .main, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
    setupViews()



}
let animationDuration = 60.0
let animationStartDate = Date()


@objc func handleProgressAnimation() {
    let currenttime = Date()
    let elapsed = currenttime.timeIntervalSince(animationStartDate)


    let percentage = elapsed / animationDuration
    timeRemainingView.frame.size.width = CGFloat(400 - (400 * percentage))

}
```

Anything tips or suggestions?

Comment: Typical table view cell reuse issue. Read more about table views and how it reuses it's cells.

Comment: I have read so much on this! The issue happens mostly when animating the tableviewcell content. I have read other similar questions here but still not working out. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: If you want the animation to appear to continue while the table row is off screen then you can't use a simple `UIView.animate`.  You will need to use a repeating timer and update each visible cell each time it triggers.  That way you can update your model even when cells are off screen and render the bar at the appropriate size when the cell comes back on screen.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you provide me with some sample code thx

Answer (score -2):

Replace your cellForRowAtIndex like this:

```
    let identifier = "homeCell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as! listTableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "listTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? listTableViewCell
    }
    cell.testlabel.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
return cell
```

Comment: I'm afraid this code won't even compile and if it did, it would crash, and it doesn't solve the problem which is caused by cell reuse.

Comment: Since iOS 6, you should be using `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String, for indexPath: IndexPath)` to do this